# TFS Java SDK create PendingChange[] object

Tags: java, tfs

I'm developing a plugin for my software that will manage Microsoft TFS. Each plugin operation(check out, create label, check in, etc.) has to be run individually. My checkout operation creates a workspace, downloads that workspace, and then deletes the workspace mapping, but leaves the files behind to be built or modified.

Now, once the files are modified I need to check them back in. Since I deleted the workspace already, I'll have to make a new one.

I'm having trouble making a PendingChange[] object from the files in the workspace. Could anyone give any samples on how this would be done?

This is the code I'm using to create my workspace, if it helps:

```
public Workspace createWorkspace(String pWorkspaceName, String pLocalPath, String pServerPath)
{
WorkingFolder[] foldersToMap = null;
if (pServerPath != null && pLocalPath != null)
    {
      final List<WorkingFolder> folderList = new ArrayList<WorkingFolder>();
      folderList.add(new WorkingFolder(pServerPath, LocalPath.canonicalize(pLocalPath), WorkingFolderType.MAP, RecursionType.FULL));
      foldersToMap = folderList.toArray(EMPTY_WORKING_FOLDER_ARRAY);
    }
    else if (pServerPath == null || pServerPath.isEmpty())
    {
      //throw
    }
    else if (pLocalPath == null || pLocalPath.isEmpty())
    {
      //throw
    }

Workspace w =
  mVersionControlClient.createWorkspace(foldersToMap, pWorkspaceName, VersionControlConstants.AUTHENTICATED_USER, VersionControlConstants.AUTHENTICATED_USER, null /*Comment*/,
                                        WorkspaceLocation.SERVER, WorkspaceOptions.NONE);

return w;
}
```

Microsoft's documentation isn't great on the java sdk, so any help is appreciated.

P.S. If there's anything wrong with my question, or if you want clarification, leave a comment and let me know before you downvote, I'll get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Workspace ws = vcc.getWorkspace(workspaceName, ownerName);
PendingSet pendings = ws.getPendingChanges();
for (PendingChange pending : pendings.getPendingChanges()) {
    ItemType type = pending.getItemType();
    /*Don't download if it is a Folder*/
    if (type.getWebServiceObject().getName()
            .equals("Folder"))
        continue;
    ChangeType change = pending.getChangeType();
    Item item = vcc.getItem(pending.getServerItem());
    String itemName = StringUtils.getItemName(item.getServerItem());

    /*My business rule: can't download if isn't in Lock with owner*/
    if (!change.toString().contains("(512): Lock")) {
        returns.add(new Return("ERROR", "The object "
+ item.getServerItem()
+ " isn't in Lock with " + owner
+ "."));
            continue;
    }
    String destinationFile = destinationPath + "\\" + itemName;
    item.downloadFile(vcc, destinationFile);

}
```

Hope to be helpful.